# Uploading new application with Push Notifications. How to approach this?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app on the App Store and the Xcode project on my computer. I would like to upload the app as a completely new app on iTunes since this is such a large update. In addition, I want to implement push notifications on the new version so I sort of want a "clean slate" if possible with this new app in terms of the certificates and such. I can't find anything on how to approach this? Do I just clone my project and change the bundle ID? I want to make sure I don't mess any of the sensitive profiles or certificates up. Any advice, or general steps to take? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to update existing with PushNotification then just edit your bundle ID and enable push notification then generate APNS certificates and implement push notification code in project and generate related certificates and submit again in app store.

Comment: @Jaimin Patel is right try this link :"http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1" to make push certificates